# How does transform manager work

Tags: actionscript-3, transformation

I'm trying to do something about transform tools in as3. And I found [this](http://blog.ryantan.net/2012/07/free-transform-manager-as3-v1-5-1/)

which so helpful to me. However, I still have so many questions.

First, if I want to transform some custom image. What should I do? I try`Bitmap`

but it's not working. I dont know which class should I pick to make image transform.

Second, if I want to transform `TextField`. What should I do? I try `flash.text.TextField`

.It's work but my text is disappear when scaling.

Please give me some advice about transform tool. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have put your content into a `Sprite` and then register it to the transformer. This is the example that comes in the link you provided...

```
public var fts:FreeTransformManager;
public var mySprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

// here you initialize the transformer
fts = new FreeTransformManager(false);

// this is just something to have some content
mySprite.graphics.beginFill(0xEEEEEE);
mySprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 90, 90);
mySprite.graphics.endFill();
addChild(mySprite);

// here you register the Sprite to the transformer
fts.registerSprite(mySprite);
```